# This code not working to edit loggedin Users profile . Why?

Tags: php, sql-update, edit

This code defined as edit loggedin users profile. Show all info of loggedin user as well all code running without error. but doesn't update the users info.

show success message that it is updated. but actually no update occur in the database.

and in the URL not show any id refer that is now editing .

edit.php

```
<?php
// We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
    session_start();
    // If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
    {   header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
//iconic19base Connection
require 'inc/connect.php';
require 'inc/head.php';
// We don't have the phone or email info stored in sessions so instead we can get the results from the database.
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT student_id, name, name_bangla, photo ,phone, email, blood, district, address, address_bangla FROM iconic19 WHERE id = ?');
// In this case we can use the account ID to get the account info.
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($student_id, $name, $name_bangla, $photo, $phone, $email, $blood, $district, $address, $address_bangla);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();


//Get student_id from iconic19base
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM iconic19 WHERE id =" .$_SESSION['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}


//Update Information
if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $name_bangla = $_POST['name_bangla'];
    $blood = $_POST['blood'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $district = $_POST['district'];
    $address_bangla = $_POST['address_bangla'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $update = "UPDATE iconic19 SET student_id='$student_id', name='$name',name_bangla='$name_bangla',blood='$blood',email='$email',phone='$phone',district='$district',address_bangla='$address_bangla',address='$address' WHERE id=". $_SESSION['id'];
    $up = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    if(!isset($sql)){
        die ("Error $sql" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: home.php");
    }
}
?>

<!--Create Edit form -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
      <div class="center-login">
        <h2 class='header-2'>১৯ এর ডায়েরি</h2>

<form id="edit" method="post">

<label>Student ID:</label><input type="text" name="student_id" placeholder="student_id" value=" <?=$student_id?>" maxlength="10" readonly><br/><br/>
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" value="<?=$name?>" required><br/><br/>
<label>নাম:</label><input type="text" name="name_bangla" placeholder="name_bangla" value="<?=$name_bangla?>" required><br/><br/>
<label>Blood:</label><input type="text" name="blood" placeholder="blood" value="<?=$blood?>" required><br/><br/>
<label>Email:</label><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" value="<?=$email?>" required><br/><br/>
<label>Phone:</label><input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="phone" value="<?=$phone?>" maxlength="11" required><br/><br/>
<label>District:</label><input type="text" name="district" placeholder="district" value="<?=$district?>" required><br/><br/>
<label>Address_bangla:</label><input type="text" name="address_bangla" placeholder="address_bangla" value="<?=$address_bangla?>" required></input>
<label>Address:</label><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="address" value="<?=$address?>" required></input>
<button type="submit" name="btn-update" id="btn-update" onClick="update()"><strong>Update</strong></button>
<a href="home.php"><button type="button" value="button">Cancel</button></a>
</form>
</div>
    </body>
<!-- Alert for Updating -->
<script>
function update(){
    var x;
    if(confirm("Updated ১৯ এর  ডায়েরি Sucessfully") == true){
        x= "update";
    }
}
</script>
</body>

<style>
#edit button[type="button"] {

    background: #b10e08;


  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;

  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px; 

}
.center-login {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: unset;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: unset;
    padding: unset;
    background: unset;
    border-radius: unset;


}

#edit input[type="text"],
#edit input[type="email"],
#edit input[type="tel"],
#edit input[type="url"],
#edit input[type="number"],
#edit textarea,
#edit button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#edit {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
       border-radius: 4px;
}

#edit h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#edit h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#edit input[type="text"],
#edit input[type="email"],
#edit input[type="tel"],
#edit input[type="url"],
#edit input[type="number"],
#edit textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#edit input[type="text"]:hover,
#edit input[type="email"]:hover,
#edit input[type="tel"]:hover,
#edit input[type="url"]:hover,
#edit input[type="number"]:hover,
#edit textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#edit textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#edit button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#edit button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#edit button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#edit input:focus,
#edit textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

</style>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you using an 'UPDATE' where you should be using a 'INSERT'? It'll update 0 rows, since no rows match that id.

Comment: With 'INSERT' Not working. and "id & student_id" these are different things.

Comment: _"not working"_ See if you're getting an error. You're probably using the wrong syntax for an INSERT statement. Note: you won't get an error if you're updating 0 rows, but you WILL get an error if your insert statement is "not working".

Comment: You can use something like `mysqli_error->error()` to see if there are errors. Just google "mysqli php show errors".

Comment: Where are you getting or showing a success message? $up is assigned but never used to see if things worked or not. As a matter of fact the user is blindly redirected to home if sql query is not empty.

Comment: MySQL returns errors differently than regular PHP. Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after each step to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: `if(!isset($sql)){
        die ("Error $sql" .mysqli_connect_error());` isn't doing what you think you want it to do